# lightning-input type=datetime [Unable to set / consider the locale time for the validation as per the Locale of the User]

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-design-system, javascript-controller, lwc-oss

***.html snippet (LWC Component)***

[image]

***.js snippet (LWC Component)***

import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class DateTimePickerLightningInput extends LightningElement {

```
@track today;

connectedCallback(){

    this.today = new Date().toLocaleString();

}
```

}

***Outcome:***

[image] [image]

As per the above outcome, the Current Locale DateTime = 10/19/2022, 5:50:37 PM. But, if you could see that the lightning-input with type=datetime component is considering the DateTime = Oct 19, 2022, 9:50:37 AM and thus the validation message is dependent on the DateTime Value = Oct 19, 2022, 9:50:37 AM.

Is there any way for the lightning-input component to consider the Current Locale DateTime = 10/19/2022, 5:50:37 PM based on the User Location / Region Timezone?

Thanks in Advance !!!

***Outcome using Date().toISOString() as below:***

[image] [image]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The below approach has helped to resolve the issue:

**Approach:**

- Using 2 different lightning components for Date & Time with having the below logic implemented the issue was resolved.
- Also, the Past Date & Time is disabled with the below Logic.

DisablePastDateTime.html

[image]

DisablePastDateTime.js

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try using this -

```
connectedCallback(){

    this.today = new Date().toISOString();

}
```

Comment: Then you can pass your variable today directly to apex with parameter type Datetime.

Comment: I have tried your suggested line of code as well (i.e., this.today = new Date().toISOString();) but that too does not work !!

Comment: You can also define timezone in input field. But as per my knowledge lwc considers current user timezone. for datetime fields. Can you share screenshot after the above changes?

Comment: Alternately, you can send the today variable in apex with Datetime type parameter and return `today.format()` from apex with return type as string.

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not add the screenshot in the comment section. But, I have added the screenshot after using toISOString() for reference in the description of this post itself. @Gaurav Suther

Comment: Okay, as I am not sure what are actual requirement but the easiest solution I can suggest you is that you can call apex method in connected callback and return Datetime.now() from apex. Also check user locale and timezone of current user.

Comment: You can comment your apex code and LWC code (JS and HTML). That might help.

Comment: I tried but I think so for type=datetime it takes the default time...

Comment: I tried another approach of having 2 different lightning components one for a date and the other for a time. Then, I was able to achieve the outcome. At least, I was able to get the Date and Time as per My Locale by making use of getTimezoneOffset()... !!! Then, passing those values to Min Attribute in the .html logic... !!!

Comment: Anyways do you have any idea how these 2 different components (i.e., Date & Time) can be leveraged in the Lightning-Datatable?

Comment: I mean to ask if can we bind the Lightning:input for date/time into the Lighting:datatable [As Disabling Past Dates & Time Logic is implemented for Lighting:input] ?